# How to open an encrypted PDF file by sending the password as command-line argument?

Tags: pdf, passwords, command-line-arguments

We have encrypted PDF files, requiring passwords to open. The encryption is only needed for transmission across email, but once the file is saved locally, we would like to provide buttons/shortcuts to allow the end user to open the file by double-clicking without the need to enter the password (in this case, security is not a concern once the PDF file resides on the user's local computer).

It would be nice to specify the password as a command-line argument, but apparently Adobe Reader does not support this (see [here](https://acrobatusers.com/forum/general-acrobat-topics/how-open-pdf-and-automatically-input-password/) and [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/opening-a-pdf-file-with-password-in-command-line/m-p/11122021)).

Is there possibly a way to pass the PDF Password to Chrome or Firefox's built-in PDF viewer?  I tried sending on the address bar, such as "file://c:/test/encrypted.pdf?password=mypassword" but this did not work: the password prompt still appears. I'm not finding any info about the built-in PDF viewer command line options.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course supply the password in the URL as plain text (within reason)  but it will not be actioned by the viewer as it must be entered by the client, so here after the client enters that text it will GOTO page 2

[image]

Try it your self
https://download.novapdf.com/download/samples/pdf-example-password.pdf#page=2&password=test

Here is a legacy browser where the "Password" can either have been previously stored or if a new password, be "Remembered", you are unlikely to find similar with modern extensions. **Such ability was finally depreciated from 2015 !**

[image]

Adobe have always been clear "Not just anyone can unlock your PDF. Only people with permission can remove restrictions." And perhaps not so clear about the use of passwords. So basically the "Password" cannot be used for restrictions except in Adobe or partner client receivers like Chromium Edge etc. Thus restriction removals simply need 3rd party unlockers to use the internal master key required to OPEN as your permission.

However the Privacy Password to "Open/Edit&View" is only of value to the person that adds it, since that master key is stored in the file, and never tells any one else that Key/PIN word combination. (E.G. never asks a web site to use that Key/PIN word)

From https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-mobile-discussions/password/m-p/12043962#M11961

> If you received the PDF file from someone else, you need to get the password from whoever created the PDF file.
> Otherwise, if you created the PDF file yourself, if you don't remember the password you applied to the PDF file, you are pretty much out of luck. You will need to recreate the PDF file from whatever you used to create the PDF file.
> Adobe doesn't have copies of passwords used on PDF files. Nor is there any “back door” in the PDF file format or any PDF readers to bypass any PDF passwords.

Sorry!
Dov Isaacs, former Adobe Principal Scientist

**It is still possible for Desktop PDF readers to store a set of skeleton keys** (passwords) to be applied to open any that fit such PDF file(s) but you are unlikely to find one as a Browser inbuilt extension, unless you write your own.

You ask for a solution to ***"file:///c:/test/encrypted.pdf?password=mypassword"*** (not natively possible)

What is possible is user to recall a download decrypted as
***`MSEdge.exe "file:///c:/test/DEcrypted.pdf"`***
for which you need a decryptor (easy) and a batch command (easy for a user to run, but pointless)

`open password=[pre-stored] downloaded.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to install third-party software on the user's computer, you could just decrypt the file through a command line program prior to viewing, once it is safe and local on the machine. For example:

`cpdf in.pdf owner=myownerpassword -o out.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan to send the password to the recipient, since it can't be through email? Are you planning to send some other piece of software that contains the password over a different channel? Or are the "*buttons/shortcuts to allow the end user to open the file by double-clicking*" on a web page you control?

If you do have the capability to operate a web site (with SSL obviously), you could create an page where a user can drag and drop the PDF or otherwise upload it, and that web site can then decrypt the PDF using whatever password was used with a command line PDF decrypter and finally return it to the user as a PDF that will be viewed in the same browser window using the browser PDF viewer. Of course, that web page must be password protected, but that can be autofilled by the browser.

It's not quite as convenient as double-clicking the file, but...

There are other options as well, but they require some piece of custom software to be present on the recipients computer, that gets there by some other method than email.

In the end, to maintain your target level of security, the password *must* go trough a different channel than email, since your stated target is to protect the PDF contents in transit over email. If the password in any form is sent over email, you're not achieving that.

Comment: Obviously the password can't be transmitted with the PDF. We would be using pre-shared passwords which both sender and recipient already know.

Comment: Right. But how does the password get to the recipient? Is it a password easy to remember and type, and sent over SMS or similar? Or is it embedded in some piece of software the user downloads via another channel, such as a web site download behind a login? Or? Knowing this is important in determining what options are available for a convenient model to use it with the PDF.

Comment: apologies, but we're going down the wrong path here. I simply need to be able to open an encrypted PDF file while passing in the password without the user needing to type it.  Are you aware of any other PDF viewers that support a password as command line argument? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to roll your own using a library for PDF viewing. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ seems like a viable option for example. There are others, although I don't have personal experience with any of them in this kind of context. The reason you're having trouble finding this functionality is probably because it's such a strange use-case. The whole point of the encrypting feature it is to ensure the user has to enter a password to view it, but you're trying to use it as transport security during email transit only and then go away. Maybe reconsider using PDF encryption for this.

Comment: yes I understand that the use case is unusual.  Thanks for recommending pdf.js, I will look into this.  Best regards.